# Ansible use ec2 public ip of one play in another play

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have the following ansible playbook.

```
---

- name: Ansible playbook to create a new aws dev instance
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - aws

- name: Set up the dev server
  hosts: 
  roles:
    - services
```

In the `aws` role, I am creating an ec2 instance and registering it as `ec2_instance`. How will I use the public IP of that newly created instance in the hosts of the second play.

Should I use something like `hosts: ec2_instance.public_ip`?

Comment: You should use `add_host`, see [examples](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html) in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using [add_host](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html). Put this in your first play (after getting the ip of new vm):

```
- name: Adding a new host in inventory file.
  add_host: name=someName ansible_ssh_host="{{your_ip}}" ansible_ssh_pass=*** groups=new_group
```

and then use this group in second play:

```
- name: Set up the dev server
  hosts: new_group
```